# Eliminating two zeros in a bmp array

Tags: c++, bmp

I was trying to load BMP picture into memory and save the RGB array into a file(my own format 3d model with texture data).I made the programming to convert OBJ and its texture data into a m2d file. But when I loaded the file in actual in my m2d loader it showed me green continuous lines on the picture.

I opened the BMP file in hex editor, found two 00s as culprit(occurred many times).
Any hint how should I take these 00s out of my RGB array?
Any hint or tip will be appreciated.

Comment: I am writing this from my mobile cant write whole code

Comment: Is your BMP an odd size, by any chance?

Comment: @immibis Yes .it is not at size 2^n

Comment: @Fennekin: Then post it when you're _not_ on your mobile...

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok i will post next time on pc thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each horizontal row in a BMP must be a multiple of 4 bytes long.

If the pixel data does not take up a multiple of 4 bytes, then 0x00 bytes are added at the end of the row. For a 24-bpp image, the number of bytes per row is `(imageWidth*3 + 3) & ~3`. The number of padding bytes is `((imageWidth*3 + 3) & ~3) - (imageWidth*3)`.

Comment: Ok so here horizontal row matters .thanks so I will resize bmp into multiple of 4 in width

Comment: Don't just resize this particular BMP; fix your import mechanism to handle this case.